# Uploading with ASP.NET MVC, Redirect Result View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build an uploader with ASP.NET MVC, but I'm having a bit of a problem.

The uploader occurs in a private pane that is loaded by jQuery - that is to say, it is it's own view, but it is not accessible via a View Path. Or it is not intended to be - either way, I need the page not to change once the upload is complete.

Is there any way to do this?

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/Uploads"),
                                           Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
            uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
    }

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#create">Upload</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="create">
    <h2>
        FileUpload</h2>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Management",
                FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {%>
    <input name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    <%} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is asynchronously perform your file upload so the page doesn't post back.

Here's a question about async file upload by jQuery:
[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)